# Pass nullable boolean to partial view not working when value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I'm trying to do this in my razor view:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Checkbox", Model.SomeNullableBoolean); }
```

_Checkbox.cshtml:

```
@model bool?

@if (Model == null)
{
    Some code
}
else if (Model == true)
{
    Some other code
}
```

This works fine as long as the `Model.SomeNullableBoolean` is set to either `true` or `false`.
But if the value is null I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.MyAwesomeModel_EB6A12E11ECADA2C6B22289ACDF73813854383896F2E78956FDFFE6225F0404F',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]'.

The nullable property inside the model (`MyAwesomeModel`) is defined like this:

```
public bool? SomeNullableBoolean { get; set; }
```

Any ideas how I should investigate this further?

Comment: As I know, boolean can not be null.

Comment: When you pass a model to a partial that is `null`, by default it passes the model in the main view (in your case `MyAwesomeModel`

Comment: You might be able to pass a new `ViewDataDictionary` instead (using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary%29))

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks! That worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a model to a partial which is `null`, by default it will use the model in the main view, so in your case its passing and instance of `MyAwesomeModel` to a view that expects a model which is `bool?` (hence the error).

You need to conditionally pass a new `ViewDataDictionary` if the value of the property is `null`

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Checkbox", Model.SomeNullableBoolean.HasValue ?
    new ViewDataDictionary(){ Model = Model.SomeNullableBoolean } : 
    new ViewDataDictionary()); }
```

Answer (score 2):

I followed Stephen Muecke's advice and went with the `ViewDataDictionary` approach:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Checkbox", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "BoolValue", Model.SomeNullableBoolean}}); }
```

_Checkbox.cshtml:

```
@{
    var theValue = (bool?) ViewData["BoolValue"];
}

@if (theValue == null)
{
    something
}
else if (theValue == true)
{
    something
}
else
{
    something
}
```

This works perfectly!